# JavaScript's XPath: How to get the attribute value of an element?

Tags: javascript, xpath

I want to get the value of an attribute of a specific element that has a specific id. For an example I want to get the `href` of the `a` tag whose `id` is *next*:

```
<a href="?page=3" id="next">Next</a>
```

I know I can get it like this:

```
console.log(document.evaluate('//a[@id="next"]', document, null, XPathResult.ANY_TYPE, null).iterateNext().href);
```

But the matter is that in my case the name of the attribute may differ and I need a way to specify it via the xpath query. Something like this:

```
'//a[@id="next"]/@href'
```

Comment: Why don't you do `$x('//a[@id="next"]')[0].getAttribute('href')`?

Comment: What does the `$x` stand for?

Comment: Chrome's console XPath function, like `$$` is for `querySelectorAll`.

Comment: You can also do `$x('//a[@id="next"]/@href')[0].value`

Comment: console.log(document.evaluate('//a[@id="next"]', document, null, XPathResult.ANY_TYPE, null).iterateNext().getAttribute(THE_ATTRIBUTE_NAME));

Answer (score 8):

Just try something like this:

```
document.evaluate('//a[@id="next"]/@href', document, null, XPathResult.ANY_TYPE, null).iterateNext().value;
```

Depending on the element type you specify in your xpath (element node, text node, attribute), `iterateNext()` returns different type of object. In this case, specifying @href attribute, it returns a javascript Attr object with the property `value` containing the value of the attribute. Continuing with your example:

```
<a href="?page=3" id="next">Next</a>
```

You can try next examples:

```js
//Returns true
console.log(document.evaluate('//a[@id="next"]/@href', document, 
  null, XPathResult.ANY_TYPE, null).iterateNext() instanceof Attr);

//Returns "?page=3"
console.log(document.evaluate('//a[@id="next"]/@href', document, 
  null, XPathResult.ANY_TYPE, null).iterateNext().value);

//Returns true
console.log(document.evaluate('//a[@id="next"]', document,
  null, XPathResult.ANY_TYPE, null).iterateNext() instanceof Node);

//Returns false
console.log(document.evaluate('//a[@id="next"]', document,
  null, XPathResult.ANY_TYPE, null).iterateNext() instanceof Attr);

//Returns true
console.log(document.evaluate('//a[@id="next"]', document,
  null, XPathResult.ANY_TYPE, null).iterateNext().nodeType === Node.ELEMENT_NODE);

//Returns "Next"
console.log(document.evaluate('//a[@id="next"]', document,
  null, XPathResult.ANY_TYPE, null).iterateNext().textContent);

//Returns true
console.log(document.evaluate('//a[@id="next"]/text()', document,
  null, XPathResult.ANY_TYPE, null).iterateNext() instanceof Node);

//Returns true
console.log(document.evaluate('//a[@id="next"]/text()', 
  document, null, XPathResult.ANY_TYPE, null).iterateNext().nodeType === Node.TEXT_NODE);

//Returns "Next"
console.log(document.evaluate('//a[@id="next"]/text()', document, 
  null, XPathResult.ANY_TYPE, null).iterateNext().nodeValue);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<a href="?page=3" id="next">Next</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Some links that could help you:

- [DOM element's attribute reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Attr)
- [Node Types](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Node/nodeType/)

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [Element.attributes property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/attributes)

`document.evaluate('//a[@id="next"]', document, null, XPathResult.ANY_TYPE, null).iterateNext().attributes['href'].value`

or the [getAttribute() method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getAttribute)

`document.evaluate('//a[@id="next"]', document, null, XPathResult.ANY_TYPE, null).iterateNext().getAttribute('href')`